# What does egg do for baked grated cheese?

Tags: baking, substitutions, eggs, cheese, cookies

Here's a [recipe](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3431501511199218/Kaesetaler-mit-Garnelen-und-Tomaten.html) for baked cheese bites. Is that what would call those? It mixes 200g grated cheese, 2 eggs, 2 tsp baking powder. I note that the surface has some smooth blisters in among the grate threads.

[image: baked grated cheese with some blisters]
<sup>(SunnyKida, chefkoch.de)</sup>

I suppose the baking powder requires some moisture, yet water wouldn't mix well with fatty cheese. But why use eggs specifically? Would something like cream cheese or cream also work here?

And if I changed the amount of egg, should the baking powder vary by the same factor or is there an upper limit?

Comment: Whether you’d want to change the amount of baking powder would depend on *why* you were changing the amount of egg.

Comment: @Sneftel The only current reason is to know what's useless to try out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When egg is cooked it becomes solid so in this recipe it is part of the substance of the finished product, holding the cheese together and contributing substance and flavour. If you have ever had an omelette you have encountered cooked egg.

Both cream cheese and cream are liquids when heated and would fall apart if cooked. The grated cheese might manage to melt together but I would expect an unappetising mess.

Comment: Thanks. I flat forgot part of the query, please see new last paragraph?

Comment: Well, a mess, certainly. Not necessarily an *unappetising* one.

Comment: @Sneftel The picture in my mind is some cheese floating in a puddle of burnt, split cream or cream cheese – but I could be wrong!

Comment: @ariola Adding new questions through an edit doesn't work well for the format of this site – I would encourage you to edit it back out and ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @dbmag9 Would you have found anything amiss had I managed to include it in the first place?